# How to get a reference to a bean from a class annotated as @ServerEndpoint (WebSocket)?

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket

I want to update a website in real time by using WebSocket to push data from within a class annotated as ServerEndpoint. Such data is to be obtained from a given bean created in the Spring xml file. @Autowire does not work, so I assume it's because my endpoint object is in a different context. How can I get such reference?

**Edit**

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to thymeleaf resources in the /WEB-INF/view directory -->
<beans:bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <beans:property name="cacheable" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
        <beans:set>
            <beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="52428800" /> <!-- 50MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <beans:property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />

<context:annotation-config />

<beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="language" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <beans:property name="interceptors">
       <beans:list>
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="ui_messages" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:import resource="serverConfiguration.xml"/> <!-- Here is where I create the bean I need -->
```

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Comment: Can you provide your spring context declarations?

Comment: For now I did a workaround by keeping a reference in a singleton class, still think there must be an elegant way.

Comment: What do you keep a reference to ? Can you explain? Having the same problem right now, how to inject beans into @ServerEndpoint class.

Comment: I just created a "reference provider" singleton class which keeps references of all beans I want to make available for endpoints and controllers.